# I had previously installed Spicetify but now while reinstalling it, I'm having this Error

Tags: powershell, spotify

[image]

iwr : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1

- iwr -useb https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spicetify/spicetify-cli/m ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
  eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
  ```

I'm having this error now. I tried various solutions from YouTube but its not working either.

I had installed previously and was working properly as well but this time when I'm trying to reinstall, its give me this error.

Comment: There are at least three possible causes of the error you saw: a problem with your internet connection, a problem with your proxy configuration, or the target server refusing a connection.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to diagnose your problem (I've given hints in my previous comment). It is not a problem with the URL or the target server (`Invoke-WebRequest https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spicetify/spicetify-cli/master/install.ps1` works fine for me).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , tried many things but in end just changing my DNS to 8.8.8.8 worked

Change your Primary DNS : 8.8.8.8
Secondary DNS : 8.8.4.4

this worked for me .
DNS Setting : Control Panel -> Network and sharing -> click on the network you are connected to -> Properties -> Select Internet Protocol version IP4 -> Change the DNS and Secondary DNS -> Apply and hope it will work .